# test string nullability in java8

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have a question in my assignment ... but need to be sure of my answer ... I will go for 2 but is that is correct or not?

Which of the following items is the correct lambda expression for testing 
string null?

```
  1- (String value) -> value != null;
  2- (value) => value != null;
  3- [String value] -> value != null;
  4- (auto value) -> value != null;
```

Comment: well for _java_ the syntax would be `(String value) -> value != null;` . option "2" is more like C# and JavaScript

Comment: 2 is not fine. `=>` is wrong, it must be `->`. @PeterLawrey

Comment: @OleV.V. correct. Missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is `(String value) -> value != null;` the first answer

Comment: oh sorry, yes I mean the first answer

Comment: You may want to explain why? For us all to learn. I agree, BTW.

Comment: The 2. answer is incorrect because `=>` is not a valid lambda expression, it should be `->`. The 3. is incorrect because of the wrong brackets `[String value]` it should be `(String value)`. And the last one is incorrect because there is no type `auto`. In my opinion, it's the first answer.